# underscore where with or condition (underscore, lodash or any other solution)

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

I implemented a mixin to add "or" condition with _.where

```
var arr = [{a:1,b:4}, {a:5}, {a:6}, {a:11}];
_.mixin({
   or: function(obj,arr,condition){
     return _.chain(arr).where(condition).union(obj).value();
   }
});
```

now i can use it like this and it works perfectly somewhat like a sql query

```
_.chain(arr).where({a:1}).or(arr,{a:11,b:3}).or(arr,{a:2}).value();
//returns [{a:1,b:4}]

_.chain(arr).where({a:1}).or(arr,{a:11}).or(arr,{a:2}).value();
//returns [{a:1,b:4},{a:11}]

_.chain(arr).where({a:1}).or(arr,{a:11}).or(arr,{b:4}).value();
//returns [{"a":1,"b":4},{"a":11}] --no duplicates
```

but I want to find a better way to just call _.or({a:1}), right now I have to pass arr everytime _.or(arr,{a:1}), as chained "or" gets first object as the result of previously executed functions.

Is there any way to get entire array in chained mixin function?

I want below to return the same result as my above implementation. (like a perfect sql query)

```
_.chain(arr).where({a:1}).or({a:11,b:3}).or({a:2}).value();//returns [{a:1,b:4}]
```

my prime focus is to get it through underscore, but really any other way like lodash or even some other library or solution will work too. Also it's not required that we use chaining, i am trying with compose as well but so far no luck. I want a solution which work perfectly in minimum lines. Any other suggestion to make it better is encouraged.

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lxqd131k/1/)

Comment: I don't rhink extending underscore is the right way. See: you have to pass through the reference of the initial array among the result so that each `or()` is able to add more subsequent results filtered from the initial collection. Underscore's chaining is not desinged for this. You may "bend" it, but at cost of your desired shortness. Implementing an fluent interface on your own is not that hard as you think - would it be OK to do it? If so please edit your question and remove the Underscore requirements (leave your examples to show what you've tried though).

Comment: well underscore and lodash both allow you to extend functionality using your custom code through mixin, you are right that chaining is not designed for this and I am open to any other concept or mechanism. let me update my question to remove underscore and chain dependencies.

Comment: ok i updated the question to make it open for all possible solutions.

Comment: Since what you're trying to do "conflicts" with the current implementation of chain, have you tried to override the chain itself to always pass the root as the last parameter?

Comment: not yet, i actually don't want to override chain as i am not sure what it will break in other part of app. can I override chain for just this instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think extending underscore is the right way, Underscore's chaining is not desinged for this. You may "bend" it, but at cost of your desired shortness.

### How chaining works

Underscore's chaining is a "stream operation". `chain()` stores the passed object internally in a closure and returns the Underscore interface where each method is bound to that object. When a filter function is applied, the result is returned and internally stored in a result object. The `value()` call will then return the internal reference.

### Custom solution

You can solve this using a so called fluent interface:

```
// Fluent interface to filter an array with chained, alternative conditions.
// Usage: whereOr([...]).or({...}).or({...}).end()
//        whereOr([...], {...}).or({...}).end()
// Objects are _.where() conditions to subsequently apply to the array.
function whereOr(arr, condition) {
    var result = [],
        iface;

    iface =  {
        or: function(subcondition) {
            result = result.concat(_.where(arr, subcondition));
            return iface;
        },
        end: function() {
            return _.union(result);
        }
    };

    if (condition) {
        return iface.or(condition);
    }

    return iface;
}
```

You can then do

```
var arr = [{a:1,b:4}, {a:5}, {a:6}, {a:11}];
whereOr(arr).or({a:1}).or({a:11}).or({a:2}).end();
```

If you like, you could mix this function into Underscore, of course:

```
_.mixin({
    whereOr: whereOr
});
```

### How it works

When `whereOr()` is called it establishes a scope that holds the reference to the original `arr`. It returns an object that provides the fluent functions `or()` and `end()` which both have access to the inital array. While `end()` will return the result, `or()` will apply Userscore's `where()` to the internal reference and add the result to `result`. It then returns the interface object again. This way `or()` provides another possibility to filter until `end()` returns the unionized result. In this example `whereOr()` optionally accepts a first filter condition as second argument.

You may compare `whereOr()` with `chain()` and `end()` with `value()`.

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6sx435bk/2/)

Comment: interesting solution, vote up for that, but this solution is not working https://jsfiddle.net/6sx435bk/1/ as its selecting first matched value only everytime. can you correct that in jsFiddle. Also I am trying to avoid passing arr everytime, can you try with passing arr to whereOr function only.

Comment: It does. [Don't call `or()` with `arr` as first argument](https://jsfiddle.net/6sx435bk/2/). Its first argument is a(nother) filter contition to `where()`. :)

Comment: cool, actually i copied it from answer, you are passing arr to each or call, can you update your answer and also add jsFiddle link to that as well. looks good. thanks :)

Comment: Thanks for fixing this (copy & paste) error in my answer - edit approved.

Answer (score 2):

This is an interesting problem to take on, thank you for bringing this to my attention Rahul!

I came up with a function that solves this problem using underscore helper functions (though without chaining). It takes 2 arguments, the `array` you start with, and the `propsObj` array with properties you want to match.

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3awhjdrk/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
// makeOr is a constructor for a 'chainable' type with: `{or, value}`
var makeOr = () =>  {
  var fs = []
  var obj = {
    or: f => {
      fs.push(f)
      return obj
    },
    value: (arr) => _.chain(fs).map(f => _.where(arr, f)).union().flatten().value()
  }     
  return obj
}

// override underscore where 
// if f is our 'chainable' type we evaluate it, otherwise we default to underscore where
(function() {
  where = _.where
  _.mixin({
    where: (arr, f) => (!!f.value && !!f.or) ? f.value(arr) : where(arr, f)
  })
})();

var result = _.chain(arr)
  .where(makeOr().or({a: 1}).or({a:5}).or({a:11}))
  .where({a:5}).value()
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5gyLy02n/2/)

PS. Check this out too: [Hey Underscore, You're Doing It Wrong!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m3svKOdZijA)

Comment: thanks homam for the link, its really interesting, i know underscore passes first argument to mixin but in my case "or" function always be used with _.where (similar to sql query) so i have to use _.chain, now if i use chain, then object passed to the next function is the result of previously executed chain functions. So, you solution will not work in that case. You can use the jsFiddle i created to check the results

Comment: I don't fully get your point. This is the updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/j8zz5qo1/ we get the same result whether with your original `or` or my `or1` which takes `arr` in its first argument.

Comment: ok check this out https://jsfiddle.net/j8zz5qo1/1/ i updated the first "or" clause to match two values. in my result you will get both the values but in yours solution you will get only first value as its matched by where clause.