# Can I use Underscore 'where' with an 'or'?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

What I'm after would be something like this (myArray is an array of objects):

```
myArray = _.where(myArray, {Flag: ""} or {Flag: exists: {false}});
```

In words, return myArray of objects that either have the Flag field value as an empty string, or where the flag field doesn't exist.

Is there a way to do this in underscore.js?

Comment: Another answered question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36230825/underscore-where-with-or-condition-underscore-lodash-or-any-other-solution with alternative solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: No

But you can use filter:

```
_.filter(myArray, function(x) {
  return x.Flag === '' || _.has(x, 'Flag');
});
```

Might be able to be simplified to:

```
_.reject(myArray, _.property('Flag'));
```

If you don't mind any other falsy values.